# Underbrace space without underbrace?

Tags: underbrace

I want to diagram what 4 KB means.

```latex
$\underbrace{4}_{2^2} \underbrace{\text{KB}}_{2^{10}}$
```

I'd like to put a multiplication sign between the two underbrace *in the underbrace space* (same level, size, etc) without the multiplication sign actually having a brace over it. And maybe even an `= 2^{12}` part at the end in the same style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

The `\mkern2mu` directive inside the argument of `\mathllap` serves to places the `\times` symbol right below the gap between the two horizontal braces. (A larger value for the argument of `\mathllap` would push the `\times` symbol further to the left.) Likewise, `\mathrlap{\cramped{\,=\,2^{12}}}` serves to place `=2^{12}` to the right of the main argument of the second `\underbrace` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathllap', '\mathrlap', and '\cramped' macros

\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{4}_{2^2} 
\underbrace{\mathrm{KB}}%
    _{\mathllap{\times\mkern2mu} 
      2^{10} % <-- main argument of '\underbrace'
      \mathrlap{\cramped{\,=\,2^{12}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```